# Pass table back to C++ using tolua++

Tags: parameters, tolua++

I need to pass a table of strings back to a C++ method from lua as a parameter, any ideas how I would mark the method that accepts the table using tolua++?

Comment: I also am interested in how to pass a lua table to an exposed C++ class method using tolua++. I tried make the parameter lua_Object but that seems to fail the tolua_isnoobj() check when the function is called.